# How to set isActive on active link in a map loop using NEXTUI navbar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using the new NEXTUI navbar: https://nextui.org/docs/components/navbar

I want to set `isActive` property on the active link and there isn't much help to get from Google so I hope someone here have used it or knows how to do so. I'm using Next.js

A portion of the code:

```
<Navbar.Content
  enableCursorHighlight
  activeColor="primary"
  hideIn="xs"
  variant="highlight-rounded"
>

  {navigation.map((item, index) => (
    <Navbar.Link key={index} href={item.link}>
      {item.title}
    </Navbar.Link>
  ))}

</Navbar.Content>
```

EDIT: When I add `isActive` in the `map` loop, it effects all. I want to set `isActive`on the clicked (active link) one at a time. If I didn't loop my nav links (which is coming from backend) I could set `IsActive` property on one but then its just that one that have `isActive` even if I click on other links.

Comment: Can you specify the problem you're facing? It seems simple, you just add the `isActive` prop on the `<Navbar.Link>` element.

Comment: When I add `isActive` in the `map` loop, it effects all. I want to set `isActive`on the clicked (active link) one at a time. If I didn't loop my nav links (which is coming from backend) I could set `IsActive` property on one but then its just that one that have `isActive` even if you click on other links.

Comment: Got it, then you can use `useState` from React with `onClick` event to handle clicks, that is, you will store the links you're getting from the backend in the state, then on any click on any of them, you will update that specific link to be active.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAli I get everything you said but my problem how I write the code. Care to give a little example code or link to somewhere else that I can follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a specific condition in your `map` to check if you are on the correct route.

For example: you can use the [`next/router`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) and compare it to the `link` property of the item.

```
 const { asPath } = useRouter();
.
.
.
//inside return body 
....
 {navigation.map((item, index) => {
    if(asPath === item.link)
   return(<Navbar.Link isActive key={index} href={item.link}>
      {item.title}
    </Navbar.Link>);
  });
  else
 return(<Navbar.Lin key={index} href=. {item.link}>
      {item.title}
    </Navbar.Link>);
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted. Didn't even know you could do that in the JSX.

Answer (score 2):

similar to the answer above but without the if/else in the return

```
{navigation.map((item, index) => (
    <Navbar.Link 
        isActive={asPath === item.link}
        key={index}
        href={item.link}
    >
        {item.title}
    </Navbar.Link>);
  ))}
```